# mocha: call a test case synchronously

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

Is it possible to call a test case synchronously with Mocha?  For example, I have the code below:

```
context('Context of test suite', () => {
  it('test case name', () => {
    //call expect() a few times
  })
})
console.log('foo')
```

I want to run this, but I want to guarantee that `foo` will not be printed until AFTER the test case has executed and either passed or failed.  `it` does not return a Promise, nor does `context`, so I can't do it using `then`.  Is what I want possible?

This test case exists inside the `after` block.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? I'm sure you're aware of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: I don't understand the question. I'm trying to make a test case execute synchronously.

Comment: Tests do run synchronously unless you do something asynchronous inside them.  If you are only calling `expect ()` a few times there shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: p.s. why are you putting a test in the `after` block?

Comment: Because I need to run a test after all other tests have been run.

Comment: @Mark Meyer `it()` does not run synchrinous, that is my the `console.log` statement is printed before the test is asserted. So like this he could not run two tests synchronously in one file, that's why he is aksing that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move that `console.log` into a nested `after`:

```
describe('all my tests', () => {

  it('#1', done => setTimeout(done, 500))
  it('#2', done => setTimeout(done, 500))
  it('#3', done => setTimeout(done, 500))

  after(() => {

    context('Context of test suite', () => {

      it('test case name', () => {})

      after(() => {
        console.log('foo');
      });
    })

  });

});
```

Although I have a hard time understanding why you'd use a setup like this. One issue is that you can't use this setup inside a root-level `after` (one that's outside of any `describe` block), and also, `after` isn't meant for additional tests, it's meant to clean up *after* tests.

I would probably use something like this:

```
describe('all my tests', () => {

  it('#1', done => setTimeout(done, 500))
  it('#2', done => setTimeout(done, 500))
  it('#3', done => setTimeout(done, 500))

});

describe('Context of test suite', () => {

  it('test case name', () => {})

  after(() => {
    console.log('foo');
  });
})
```

I.e. just place the suite that has to run last, well, last. You can move that last `after` outside of the suite and promote it to a root-level hook, if you like.